# Set of all elements in a k-Euclidean space is open such that the metric is greater than 1/m

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $(R^{k},d)$ and the subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^k$. For every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbf{x_0} \in \mathbb{R}^k \backslash E $ the set $$V_m = \left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x_0}) > \frac{1}{m} \right\}$$ is open.

This is part of a proof in my real analysis text, proving the Heine-Borel theorem for metric spaces. I understand that an open set is a set where every element is an interior point which is defined in my book as for some $r>0$ and for $x_0 \in E$ such that $\{x \in S| d(x,x_0)<r\}$ where our metric space is $(S,d)$ and again $E \subset S$. Based on this definition I don't understand how $V_m$ above would be open for every $m$.

Comment: The $x_0$ in the definition you uses for open sets is not the same as the $x_0$ used to define $V_m.$ In particular, $x_0\notin V_m.$ to prove $V_m$ is open, you need to prove each $x_1\in V_m$ has the property required of open sets.

Comment: Yea they use $x_0$ to show that it is interior to $\mathbb{R}^k$ \ $E$. I will try to do the method you have explained.

Comment: I got it, since the closed ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $1/m$ is the complement of $V_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and hence $V_m$ is open by the definition of a closed set. I think this is correct.

Comment: Yeah, that argument works, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x_0$ in the definition for open sets is not the same as the $x_0$ used to define $V_m.$ In particular, the latter $x_0$ is not in $V_m,$ but even if it was, you'd want to prove that **all** $x_1\in V_m$ have the open set property.

As you've said, the closed ball is closed (that requires proof, of course - "closed ball" is not by definition a closed set) so its complement is open.

Alternatively. we can prove it from the definition of open sets and the triangle inequality. (You can see this as the *proof* that the closed ball is closed, since we prove its complement is open.)

> If $x_1\in V_m,$ let $r=d(x_0,x_1)-\frac{1}{m}>0.$ Then if $$x_2\in N_r(x_1)=\{x\mid d(x_1,x)<r\}$$
> we have $$d(x_0,x_2)+r > d(x_0,x_2)+d(x_2,x_1)\geq d(x_0,x_1)$$ or $$d(x_0,x_2)>d(x_0,x_1)-r=\frac{1}{m}$$
> by the definition of $r.$ 
> So $N_r(x_1)\subseteq V_m.$